# eclipse error "could not create jvm"

Tags: eclipse, server, eclipse-jee

I recently installed eclipse oxygen for jee. 
Using java10 . Installed tomcat 9.0. The tomcat service is configured at ports 8005,8080,8009 (localhost:8080 works fine).

Created an internal instance of tomcat in eclipse and tried to start server. Got error "8080,8005,8009 already in use".

Reconfigured ports for internal tomcat instance to different ports in "server.xml" of instance. Port conflict error taken care of but now I get "cannot create JVM" error.

Looked for answers on various forums (including here) which suggested to do variations in eclipse.ini.

In eclipse.ini , the required version is Java 1.8 .
Set the Java home and path to 1.8 (I already had it installed). Java 1.8 up and working (Java -version).

Edited file eclipse.ini to add  "-vm c:/jdk1.8/bin/javaw". 
Also edited "-xmx1024" to "-xmx512" (forum Soln).
Eclipse support says never to delete eclipse.ini file as suggested by a few on forums as a solution.

The error still persists.
Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I did... Downloaded eclipse neon.
Installed neon. Maintained the same server files. Followed the same steps to create a server in eclipse neon(tomcat 8.0). Started the server and it started like a sharp knife through butter!  Used the same dynamic web project and ran on the working server and it hit the bulls eye! Then I created another tomcat 9.0 server,  stopped 8.0, started 9.0, ran project on 9.0 and bingo! 
The real problem was 'oxygen',I still would like to know y it did not work on oxygen n how to get it working but also y do they release products with bugs and then ask the user to make changes in relevant files.. senseless!
I spent a few days trying to get the server working and the message 'server started, synchronised' felt like paradise. Hell Yeah!! 
Sick oxygen,  good lad neon!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have both the overall Oxygen Update Site and `http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/oxygen/` enabled on your **Available Software Sites** preference page and then **Check for Updates** from the **Help** menu. Support for Java 10 with Tomcat was a little late.

[Relevant bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533162)